# Conditioning on both sigma algebras and events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I've recently come across the following notation: given independent discrete random variables $I_1,\ldots,I_k$ on a probability space and another random variable $W$ defined on it, such that $\{W=k\}\in\sigma(I_1,\ldots,I_k)$, the following conditional probability is well defined: $\mathbb{P}(A|I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_k,W=k)$ for some event $A$. Now, I am familiar with conditioning on the $\{I_j\}$ alone (that is on $\sigma(I_1,\ldots,I_k)$) and on events alone (that is on $(W=k)$ alone), but how does this mixed case arise? I simply wonder what its definition is. What role does the measurability of $(W=k)$ plays a in this definition? I know that since the random variables are discrete, we could just work with $\mathbb{P}(A|I_1=i_1,I_2=i_2,\ldots,I_k=i_k,W=k)$ and probably leave it at that. But then the question would arise anyway: if the $I_k$ were not discrete, would this mixed conditional probability still be well-defined? My attempt was to interpret the expression as $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(A|I_1,\ldots,I_k)|W=k]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(1_A|I_1,\ldots,I_k)|W=k]=\mathbb{P}(A|W=k)$, by the definition of conditional expectation and measurability in the hypothesis, but I am not sure this is the correct interpretation of the expression.
Thank you for any insight you might be able to share.
Link to the paper: https://scholar.google.com/scholar_url?url=https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-28/issue-3/Sum-the-odds-to-one-and-stop/10.1214/aop/1019160340.pdf&hl=en&sa=T&oi=ucasa&ct=ufr&ei=N_BHZMbTMqiI6rQPlL-HGA&scisig=AJ9-iYv9tgIfEcKmKJcKwq3hHQ-Z. (second line of p.3).

Comment: Conditioning on $(W=k)$ is same as conditioning on the random variable $1_{W=k}$

Comment: You mean that $\mathbb{P}(A|I_1,\ldots,I_k,W=k)$ is an abuse of notation for  $\mathbb{P}(A|I_1,\ldots,I_k,1_{W=k})$?

Comment: The relationship that shows the connection between conditioning of a simple RV $1_A$ on another one $1_B$ vs. conditioning with events is $$\mathbb E[1_A|1_B]=\mathbb P(A|B)1_B+\mathbb P(A|B^c)1_{B^c}\,.$$ It is not an abuse of notation (and quite common) to write the LHS as $\mathbb P(A|1_B)\,.$ If it is clear from the context that your authors mean by $\mathbb P(A|1_B,C)$ the same as what most people mean by $\mathbb E[1_A|1_B,1_C]$ or $\mathbb P(A|1_B,1_C)$ then I think it is a bit over-pedantic to call that an abuse of notation.

Comment: The thing is I am not sure at all that that is what is meant, I actually think it means what I write in my attempt, from how the calculations turn out. Is the interpretation in my attempt and $\mathbb{P}(A|I_1,\ldots,I_k,1_{W=k})$ the same thing? I am not sure at all.

Comment: I wonder if some commenters are missing the point. Namely, $\Bbb E(X|Y)$ is a function of $Y$ (i.e. a random variable whose value depends on that of $Y$) whereas $\Bbb P(A|B)$ is a constant that does not "depend on $1_B$" in the way $\Bbb E(1_A|1_B)$ does. I'd expect $\Bbb P(A|Y,B)$ to be a random variable of the form $f(Y)$ where $f(y)=\Bbb P(A|Y=y,B)$ in the discrete case. This r.v. never gives $\Bbb P(A|Y=y,B^c)$, even at outcomes outside $B$.

Comment: Exactly, one interpretation leads to a random variable, the other (given in the attempt) to a function of $k$. I suspect also a third interpretation, to which I hinted, is that by $I_1,\ldots,I_k$ the author means $I_1=i_1,\ldots,I_k=i_k$ in the conditioning. But the notation is not explained, just used and just in one equation. It's hard to tell, but by the looks of these comments, it does not seem to be standard after all.

Comment: @Karl I expect $\mathbb P(A|Y,B)$ to be a random variable of the form $f(Y,\color{red}{1_B})\,.$ Not of $f(Y)$ or $f(Y)1_B\,.$ I reiterate again $$\mathbb E[1_A|1_B]=\mathbb P(A|B)1_B+\mathbb P(A|B^c)1_{B^c}\,.$$ It is quite simple to check that this RV satisfies all properties of the conditional expectation. And yes: it can take non zero values outside $B$. Otherwise, even the tower property would not hold.

Comment: Just to be sure: in that formula I reiterated: $\mathbb P(A|B)=\mathbb P(A\cap B)/\mathbb P(B)$ (which is a number) and same for the other (event based) conditional probability $\mathbb P(A| B^c)$.